# sshfs is failing with "remote host has disconnected"

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, sftp, sshfs

I'm running sshfs with the following:

```
sshfs basicuser@192.168.1.111:/var/www/myapp /home/basicuser/code -o sftp_server="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
```

I have also created RSA keys so I can log in via ssh without password prompt (I tested this and it works).

I have also added the user to the sudoers file to run the sftp-server without a password:

```
basicuser  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD:  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

What could be causing this error? How do I figure that out?

**Edit**

I am trying to mount a folder on the local computer from the remote server. On the remote server, only root has read/write permissions to that folder.

Remote folder:    /var/www/myapp (is root only read/write)

Comment: Why do you need `sftp-server` on the server to run as root?

Comment: @DanD. The folder that I'll be mounting on the local computer is root-only on the remote server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was requiring tty (this basically means something cannot be run in the background, but needs an active terminal window to run). So I added the following to `/etc/sudoers` (edited by doing `visudo`):

```
Defaults:basicuser !requiretty
```

I want it to not require tty only for that one command, but it may not be possible to do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80159

Answer (score 49):

You get a lot more information about the failure if you run sshfs as:

```
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug user@host ...
```

Usually this will give you something a lot more helpful to debug the problem.

Comment: Another trick is to disable the settings in `$HOME/.ssh/config` with `sshfs -F=none`. Ths will expose any ssh config sessions that could be causing the error, for example `RequestTTY = yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Alex Hofsteede for the debugging info.
my problem was that I was using a custom cipher, the Blowfish cipher.
`command-line line 0: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'blowfish-cbc'.`
I removed the custom cipher and it worked.

Comment: why are you posting this as an answer? this should be a comment on his answer

Comment: It is an answer to remote host disconnected question. `What could be causing this error? How do I figure that out?` It just didn't happen to be the answer the OP was looking for. However i had the same question and this was my answer.

Comment: @codenamejames The process to determine your specific issue was the answer. Your *comment* is orphaned and forces others to backtrack your "answer" to the one that will actually help the other 90% of users without a broken Blowfish cipher.